# Uncertainties of coefficients in linear fit

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, computational-physics

I'm trying to calculate the uncertainty of the coefficients in a linear fit, but I'm not sure how to do it.
on the one hand, I can extract the error with matlab statistical tools but on the other hand I need to take into account the uncertainty of my measurement (Let's say I measure pressure in a chamber and I have some degree of uncertainty that based on the measurement tool), and I dont know how to put it in my statistical calculations in matlab.

the code that I'm using now to evaluate the uncertainties is:
[z,s]=polyfit(t,lnP,1);
ste =sqrt(diag(inv(s.R)*inv(s.R')).*s.normr.^2./s.df);

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can't you use the confidence interval for this purpose?

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming/coding.

Comment: I think this question could be on topic if it is made to be more about the uncertainty in linear fits due to measurement errors (which I still think the CI can be used here) than 'how to do it in Matlab.' But at the same time, I think Qmechanics might be right and that this question might be better suited for [stats.se].

Comment: Hi! Yes, this is what I mean  - Kyle understood my question when he commented : "How are uncertainties in the of measurement accounted for in linear fits" .  I'm measuring the pressure inside a chamber that connects to a rotary pump. from the linear fit of ln(P) I can calculate the effective pump speed. My problem is how to evaluate the uncertainty of this result. On the one hand I can calculate it from the linear fit (Like Kevin estimated in his comment)

Comment: but I can also calculate like Kevin mentioned in eq.9 and not from the goodness of the linear fit. What is the right way? Or maybe there is a way to take into account the uncertainty for each measurment in the statistical calculations.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume you have N data points of the form $(x_i,y_i\pm s_i)$, and you want some function of x to approximate y.  I'll assume a more general form for the fitting function, but it will be applicable (and much simpler) in the case of a linear fit.
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x^{e_i}$$
For a linear fit, the exponents ${e_i}$ will just be zero and one, and you'll need to optimize the coefficients ${c_i}$.

I assume you're doing a least-squares fit, so the quantity you'll want to minimize is $\chi^2$:
$$\chi^2=\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{y_i-f(x_i)}{s_i}\right)^2$$

To minimize this with respect to $c_i$, you'll need to find a stationary point such that $\frac{\partial\chi^2}{\partial c_i}=0$ for all $c_i$.
This can be cast as a system of linear equations:
$$\frac{\partial\chi^2}{\partial c_k}=2\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{y_i-f(x_i)}{s_i}\right)\left(-\frac{x_i^{e_k}}{s_i}\right)=0$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{y_i-\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x_i^{e_j}}{s_i}\right)\left(-\frac{x_i^{e_k}}{s_i}\right)=0$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{x_i^{e_k}\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x_i^{e_j}}{s_i^2}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{y_i x_i^{e_k}}{s_i^2}\right)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{x_i^{e_k+e_j}}{s_i^2}\right)c_j=\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{y_i x_i^{e_k}}{s_i^2}\right)$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^n A_{kj}c_j=b_k$$
$$c_k=\sum_{j=1}^n A_{kj}^{-1}b_j$$
Where
$$A_{kj}=\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{x_i^{e_k+e_j}}{s_i^2}\right)$$
$$b_k=\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{y_i x_i^{e_k}}{s_i^2}\right)$$

The variance $\sigma_i^2$ of each coefficient $c_i$ can be estimated by ([see equation 9](http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Analytical_Chemistry/Quantifying_Nature/Significant_Digits/Propagation_of_Error))
\begin{align*}
\sigma_i^2 &= \sum_{j=1}^N s_j^2 \left(\frac{\partial c_i}{\partial y_j}\right)^2\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^N s_j^2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial A_{ik}^{-1}b_k}{\partial y_j}\right)^2\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^N s_j^2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}^{-1}\frac{\partial b_k}{\partial y_j}\right)^2\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^N s_j^2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}^{-1}\frac{x_j^{e_k}}{s_j^2}\right)^2
\end{align*}

So as long as $A$ is invertible, you can use the procedure above to find uncertainties in your coefficients.

edit:
the $\sigma_i^2$ actually simplify a bit further:

\begin{align*}
\sigma_i^2 &= \sum_{j=1}^N s_j^2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}^{-1}\frac{x_j^{e_k}}{s_j^2}\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^N s_j^2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}^{-1}\frac{x_j^{e_k}}{s_j^2}\right)\left(\sum_{l=1}^n A_{il}^{-1}\frac{x_j^{e_l}}{s_j^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n A_{ik}^{-1} A_{il}^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{x_j^{e_l+e_k}}{s_j^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n A_{ik}^{-1} A_{il}^{-1}A_{lk}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}^{-1} \delta_{ik}\\
\sigma_i^2&=A_{ii}^{-1}
\end{align*}
So your function of x is now 
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (c_i \pm \sigma_i)x^{e_i}$$
The uncertainty in the evaluation of the function at some point $x_j$ can be estimated similarly to how the uncertainty in coefficients was calculated.

\begin{align*}
\sigma_{f(x_j)}^2 &=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial f(x_j)}{\partial c_i}\right)^2 \sigma_i^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_j^{e_i}\right)^2 \sigma_i^2
\end{align*}

Given some point $x_i$, the value given by the fit will be $f(x_i)$, and the uncertainty (one std. deviation) will be $\sigma_{f(x_i)}$ (as defined above)

Comment: This seems to answer the question "How does one do a linear fit?" which isn't what OP asked. They asked "How are uncertainties in the of measurement accounted for in linear fits?"

Comment: @Kyle Kanos He asked how to calculate the uncertainties in the coefficients of a linear fit, which I explained how to do.  I included the steps for the rest of the fitting process because I thought the expressions for the uncertainties would make more sense in that context.

Comment: That is what the first sentence says, but [OP has clarified](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304420/uncertainties-of-coefficients-in-linear-fit/304457?noredirect=1#comment684387_304420) that my interpretation of the question is what he was aiming for: he has error in data-taking and wants *that* accounted for in his statistical analysis.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on the original question, but I don't see what the OP is asking for.  Given uncertainties in the $y$ values (error in data-taking), I show how to determine uncertainties in the coefficients and subsequently how to determine the uncertainty in the value of the linear fit at any point (error in model).   The $\chi^2$ value can also be used in some kind of [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) (error in analysis?).